# Setting an object class and then getting from it in the same method, looping through JSON and getting by value instead of key

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Basically I am trying to loop through a JSONArray and based on the value of one of the keys in one of the objects I am trying to get the value of another key in the same object.

More specifically, I have a value that I want to pass in to a method, and in that method I want to loop through a JSONArray, and when the loop finds the JSONObject with the value I have passed in, I want to use the object to set a new value.

I have tried looping through the JSONArray and setting values in a model class and then getting from the same model class when the loop finds the value I am looking for.

I am a beginner programmer so I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

Here is the method I have been trying:

```
private String getTeamAbbrev(String jsonData, Integer opponentTeamId) {
    Team[] teams = null;
    String opponentAbbrev = null;
    try {
        JSONArray root = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        teams = new Team[root.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++){

        JSONObject jsonTeam = root.getJSONObject(i);
        Team team = new Team();

        team.setTeamId(jsonTeam.getInt("team_id"));
        team.setCity(jsonTeam.getString("city"));
        team.setAbbrev(jsonTeam.getString("abbreviation"));
        team.setFullName(jsonTeam.getString("team_name"));

        teams[i] = team;

        if(team.getTeamId() == opponentTeamId)) {
    opponentAbbrev = team.getAbbrev();
}

    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return opponentAbbrev;
}
```

Here is the model class I have made:

```
public class Team {

private String mAbbrev;
private String mCity;
private Integer mTeamId;
private String mFullName;

public String getAbbrev() {
    return mAbbrev;
}

public void setAbbrev(String abbrev) {
    mAbbrev = abbrev;
}

public String getCity() {
    return mCity;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    mCity = city;
}

public Integer getTeamId() {
    return mTeamId;
}

public void setTeamId(Integer teamId) {
    mTeamId = teamId;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return mFullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    mFullName = fullName;
}
}
```

JSON looks like this:

```
[ { "abbreviation" : "ATL",
"city" : "Atlanta",
"team_id" : 1610612737,
"team_name" : "Hawks"
},
{ "abbreviation" : "BOS",
"city" : "Boston",
"team_id" : 1610612738,
"team_name" : "Celtics"
},
{ "abbreviation" : "CLE",
"city" : "Cleveland",
"team_id" : 1610612739,
"team_name" : "Cavaliers"
},
{ "abbreviation" : "NOP",
"city" : "New Orleans",
"team_id" : 1610612740,
"team_name" : "Pelicans"
}]
```

Based on the "team_id" I have gotten from a separate api request, I want to get the value of the "abbreviation" key.

and here is the debug at line

```
if(team.getTeamId() == (opponentTeamId)) {opponentAbbrev = team.getAbbrev(); }

this = {oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1.MatchupActivity@831701908048}
jsonData = {java.lang.String@831708371144}"[ { "abbreviation" : "ATL",\n    "city" : "Atlanta",\n    "team_id" : 1610612737,\n    "team_name" : "Hawks"\n  },\n  { "abbreviation" : "BOS",\n    "city" : "Boston",\n    "team_id" : 1610612738,\n    "team_name" : "Celtics"\...
opponentTeamId = {java.lang.Integer@831708367536}"1610612740"
value = 1610612740
teams = {oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1.DataModel.Team[30]@831708408096}
[0] = {oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1.DataModel.Team@831708408232}
mAbbrev = {java.lang.String@831708378296}"ATL"
mCity = {java.lang.String@831708378536}"Atlanta"
mFullName = {java.lang.String@831708378944}"Hawks"
value = {char[5]@831708379008}
hashCode = 0
offset = 0
count = 5
mTeamId = {java.lang.Integer@831708408328}"1610612737"
opponentAbbrev = null
root = {org.json.JSONArray@831708378040}"[{"abbreviation":"ATL","team_id":1610612737,"team_name":"Hawks","city":"Atlanta"},{"abbreviation":"BOS","team_id":1610612738,"team_name":"Celtics","city":"Boston"},{"abbreviation":"CLE","team_id":1610612739,"team_name"...
values = {java.util.ArrayList@831708378096} size = 30
i = 0
jsonTeam = {org.json.JSONObject@831708378120}"{"abbreviation":"ATL","team_id":1610612737,"team_name":"Hawks","city":"Atlanta"}"
nameValuePairs = {java.util.HashMap@831708378136} size = 4
team = {oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1.DataModel.Team@831708408232}
mAbbrev = {java.lang.String@831708378296}"ATL"
mCity = {java.lang.String@831708378536}"Atlanta"
mFullName = {java.lang.String@831708378944}"Hawks"
mTeamId = {java.lang.Integer@831708408328}"1610612737"
teams[i] = {oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1.DataModel.Team@831708408232}
mAbbrev = {java.lang.String@831708378296}"ATL"
mCity = {java.lang.String@831708378536}"Atlanta"
mFullName = {java.lang.String@831708378944}"Hawks"
mTeamId = {java.lang.Integer@831708408328}"1610612737"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `==` for String comparison.

Try this:

```
    if(team.getTeamId().equals(opponentTeamId)) {
        opponentAbbrev = team.getAbbrev().toString();
    }
```

Good luck.

Comment: appreciate it! I changed this in my code, but still no luck.

Comment: Now you are using integer, so you have to use == to comparison.

Comment: thanks, so I think I have two ints now, still no luck

Comment: Can you show the debug screen at step `if(team.getTeamId() == opponentTeamId))` ?

Comment: I posted the debug line, I didn't know if there was a way to make the formatting any better. I tried to open up some of the tabs

Comment: How about `opponentAbbrev = team.getAbbrev();`, whether your app can reach this line (I mean `team.getTeamId() == opponentTeamId)` is true)?